# Can a custom View change its position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I wrote a custom view. Depending on its content I want to move it a little bit up that it overlaps the `ImageView`.

To do this I set a new Y value in `onLayout`. The view moves up but there is now a blank space left below the view :-(

`onLayout` in my custom view:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    setY(getY() - mOverlap);
}
```

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/eventitem_background">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_cell_event"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="266%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"/>

        <me.veents.ui.views.EventListView
            android:id="@+id/eventListView_cell_event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView_cell_event"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: To set the view's Y position, better do that in `onDraw()` than `onLayout()` or include the `nineolddroids` library as it will allow you to access the views' X/Y positions as well as animate their transitions to new values. Otherwise, first move it, then call `super.onLayout(changed, left, top-mOverlap, right, bottom-mOverlap);` but i'm not sure that will work.

Comment: It has the same effect. It looks that the parent layout doesn't decrease its size when I move the view up.

Comment: parentLayout will never really re-size if it's child views move, to (hopefully) make it happen, you need to do `parentLayout.requestLayout();` as that will internally call `measure();` and `layout();` which will (again, hopefully) give you the result you want and update/recalculate it's dimensions.

Comment: If you move Y position, you don't change item size, as result you have white space. You could try to add padding with location move. Padding will increase you view size, so when you move it up (Y position) you will compensate with same padding bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use:

1) FrameLayout -- it draws its children one on top of another

2) empty views (`<View .../>`) below and above your view, you will position your view specifying the heights of these empty views. (The same technique will work for horizontal positioning.)